# Me hace print del objeto java como lo representa internamente

Tags: java, poo, eclipse, objeto, consola

estoy haciendo un print de un objeto y uno de las cosas que le pide es la ubicacion de ese objeto, pero en vez de mostarme el nombre me muestra esto.
Tengo las clase abstracta Edificio, la clase almacen, la clase producto y la clase puerta.

El print que hago es puerta1.print

```
localizacion actual: Edificios.Almacen@606d8acf
```

Me salta segun como lo representa java que deberia de hacer?

Clase Edificio abstracta

```
//-----ATRIBUTOS-----
protected float anchura;
protected float altura;
protected float profundidad;
protected String material;
protected String tipoEdificio;
protected float precio;
protected String color;

//-----MÉTODOS CONSTRUCTORES-----
public Edificio() {
    this.anchura = 0.0f;
    this.altura = 0.0f;
    this.profundidad = 0.0f;
    this.material = "";
    this.tipoEdificio = "";
    this.precio = 30.0f;
    this.color = "";
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("Anchura: " + this.anchura + " metros");
    System.out.println("Altura: " + this.altura + " metros");
    System.out.println("Profundidad: " + this.profundidad + " metros");
    System.out.println("Material: " + this.material);
    System.out.println("Edificio: " + this.tipoEdificio);
    System.out.println("Precio: " + this.precio + " €");
    System.out.println("Color: " + this.color);
}
```

La clase Producto

```
//-----ATRIBUTOS-----
public static int idProducto = 1;
protected int id;
protected String nombre;
protected String tipo;
protected float anchura;
protected float profundidad;
protected float altura;
protected String color;
protected Edificio edifActual;

//-----MÉTODOS CONSTRUCTORES-----
public Producto() {
    //this.id = 0;
    this.nombre = "";
    this.tipo = "";
    this.anchura = 0;
    this.altura = 0;
    this.color = "";
}

public Producto(float altura, float anchura, float profundidad, String nombre, String tipo, String color, Edificio edifActual) {
    this.altura = altura;
    this.anchura = anchura;
    this.profundidad = profundidad;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.color = color;
    this.edifActual = edifActual;
    id += idProducto++;
}
    
//-----MÉTODOS PROPIOS-----
public void print() {
    System.out.println(this.id);
    System.out.println(this.nombre);
    System.out.println(this.edifActual);
}
```

La clase puerta

```
public class Puerta extends Producto {
    public Puerta() {

    }

    public Puerta(float altura, float anchura, float profundidad, String nombre, String tipo, String color, Edificio edifActual) {
        super(altura, anchura, profundidad, nombre, tipo, color, edifActual);
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("id: " + this.id);
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + this.nombre);
        System.out.println("Edficio actual" + this.edifActual);
    }
}
```

La clase almacén

```
public Almacen() {
    this.anchura = 50.0f;
    this.altura = 30.0f;
    this.profundidad = 60.0f;
    this.material = "Ladrillo";
    this.tipoEdificio = "Fabrica";
    this.precio = 30.0f;
    this.color = "verde";
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("Anchura: " + this.anchura + " metros");
    System.out.println("Altura: " + this.altura + " metros");
    System.out.println("Profundidad: " + this.profundidad + " metros");
    System.out.println("Material: " + this.material);
    System.out.println("Edificio: " + this.tipoEdificio);
    System.out.println("Precio: " + this.precio + " €");
    System.out.println("Color: " + this.color);
}
```

No se por que me sale de esa forma ni logro entenderlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

casi le atinas, en vez de llamar a tu método print, debes de llamarlo `toString()` y regresar una cadena en vez de imprimirlo allí.

```
class Almacen{
public Almacen() {
    this.anchura = 50.0f;
    this.altura = 30.0f;
    this.profundidad = 60.0f;
    this.material = "Ladrillo";
    this.tipoEdificio = "Fabrica";
    this.precio = 30.0f;
    this.color = "verde";
}

public String toString() {
    String representation="Anchura: " + this.anchura + " metros";
    representation+="\nAltura: " + this.altura + " metros";
    representation+="\nProfundidad: " + this.profundidad + " metros";
    representation+="\nMaterial: " + this.material;
    representation+="\nEdificio: " + this.tipoEdificio;
    representation+="\nPrecio: " + this.precio + " €";
    representation+="\nColor: " + this.color;
    return representation;
}


}
```

Ahora que si te preguntas por qué te sale

> Edificios.Almacen@606d8acf

Es porque Object que es la clase padre de todas tiene en su método `toString` la [implementación por defecto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Y de hecho lo que hicimos fue sobre-escribir (una bonita forma técnica de decir reemplazar) el método por defecto para representar los objetos, pero solo para los objetos que sean de la clase `Almacen`. Deberás de modificar las demás clases siguiendo el mismo principio para controlar su representación cuando las mandes a imprimir, por ejemplo usando

```
Almacen almacen = new Almacen();
Systemout.println(almacen);
```

Comment: lo que me pasa ahora es que cuando llamo a puerta1 para que se imprima me imprime los datos de almacen en vez de los de puerta, Puerta1 ha de darme sus datos y el edificio donde esta ubicado

Comment: eso que te pasa ahora no es parte de esta pregunta, haz una nueva. Saludos.

Comment: pero con el print si me salen los datos de puerta